# Trying to load mixed data from csv file and searching it

Tags: matlab

I have mixed data in tab-delimited .tab files. The first column is (large) numbers, the second and third columns are (or can be treated as) text. Below is an example,

```
9984847435  cheese  0
9984847438  start   100
9984849435  orange  100
9984847635  milk    0
9984847435  coffee  1
9984847835  three_blind_mice    1
9984847435  end 1
10000000123 juice   45
10000000124 start   point
10000000223 ramen_y cattle_ranch_65.jpg
```

Now I want to import this data into matlab. Then I want to sort the table by column 1. then I want to search through this data, to for example return the row numbers (or row/column positions) of where there is 'start' in column 2.

I have used readtable to import the data as a table.

```
data = readtable ('sheet.tab', 'Format', '%u64%s%s', 'ReadVariableNames',false);

dataSorted = sortrows(data,1);

%Get row numbers for start

entry = 1;

for i = 1 : height(dataSorted)

    if dataSorted(i,2) = 'start'

        rowNumbers (entry,1) = i

        entry+1

    end

end
```

I was hoping to get a matrix listing the row numbers where there is 'start' in the second column. so for above example,

```
rowNumbers = 

2
9
```

Instead I get 'The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.'

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. I mean just a single-column matrix. I am just a beginner. the data is indeed TAB-delimited, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do an equality comparison for strings (or character arrays), and even if you could (i.e. when you're doing numeric comparisons) you want `==` not `=`.

Instead, use `strcmp`

```
if strcmp( dataSorted(i,2), 'start' )
    % stuff
end
```

Note that `ismember` is more flexible here, you can get rid of the whole loop and do

```
rowNumbers = find( ismember( dataSorted(:,2), 'start' ) );
```

Edit:

Since you're using tables, you will need to index `dataSorted` slightly differently...

```
rowNumbers = find( ismember( dataSorted{:,2}, 'start' ) );
% or using dot notation, where the 2nd column heading is 'Var2'
rowNumbers = find( ismember( dataSorted.Var2, 'start' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, this is very helpful. However when I use `ismember` as you suggested I get the error 'A and B must both be tables.' Using `strcmp (dataSorted(1,2), 'start')` comes back with 0, hence if I use the loop it doesn't return anything. I am still a little confused about formats and datatypes.

Comment: @shlabber Ah I was thinking in arrays, not tables... you can use `dataSorted{:,2}` instead, or `dataSorted.Column2Name` - I'll update my answer.